# Python import from class

Tags: python, function, class, object, import

I am a novice Python programmer and I am practicing imports but I have a problem because I don't know how to import a program from a module, thanks in advance for your help. I have tried many solutions but always some error appears....
Folder (modul) --> missile.py --> Code of Class
main.py

missile.py:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = 9.81

class Missile():

    def __init__(self, Firing_angle, Initial_velocity):
        ...

    def equation_of_trajectory(self):
        ...

    def flight_path_envelope_for_constant_speed(self):
        ...

    def axis_of_symmetry(self):
        ...

    def velocity_of_flight(self):
        ...

    def elements_of_path(self):
        ...

    def call_block(self):
        a = Pr.equation_of_trajectory()
        b = Pr.flight_path_envelope_for_constant_speed()
        c = Pr.axis_of_symmetry()
        d = Pr.velocity_of_flight()
        e = Pr.elements_of_path()
        plt.plot(a)
        plt.plot(b)
        plt.plot( )
        plt.plot(d)
        plt.show( )
        return e

    def __str__(self):
            ...


if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        try:
            Pr = Missile(float(input('Firing_angle       [o]:      ')),
                    float(input('Initial_velocity [m/s]:      ')))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong Value!')

    resume = Pr.call_block()

    print(f'Projectile launch point [m]: {resume[0]}...)
```

main.py:
ver.1

```
from Modul.missile import Missile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Missile()
```

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Firing_angle' and 'Initial_velocity'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ver.2

```
from Modul.missile import Missile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Missile()
```

and

```
def __init__(self, Firing_angle=20, Initial_velocity=120):
```

result:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ver.3

```
from Modul.missile import Missile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Firing_angle, Initial_velocity = Missile.call_block()

TypeError: call_block() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'... etc..
```

I'm out of ideas on how to do this,
thank you in advance for your help :D

Comment: It looks like you are importing just fine -- the first error you're getting is because you are creating an instance of the class without passing in any arguments for the parameters.

When you added default values that error went away ("Process finished with exit code 0").

You can't call a method on a class you haven't instantiated, that's why you get the `self` error. It's "unbound".
You want to do something like: 
`missile = Missile(Firing_angle=20, Initial_velocity=120);
missile.call_block()`
(there should be line breaks but I can't write them in-line)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things here.  Your first example is almost right.  However, your `call_block` needs to use the `self` it is given, not the global `Pr`:

```
    def call_block(self):
        a = self.equation_of_trajectory()
        b = self.flight_path_envelope_for_constant_speed()
        c = self.axis_of_symmetry()
        d = self.velocity_of_flight()
        e = self.elements_of_path()
        plt.plot(a)
        plt.plot(b)
        plt.plot(c)
        plt.plot(d)
        plt.show()
        return e
```

The bigger thing is that all the code you have inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` actually needs to be in the main file.  That code will never run when the file is imported.  So, remove that code from the module, and make your main.py:

```
from Modul.missile import Missile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            Pr = Missile(
                    float(input('Firing_angle       [o]:      ')),
                    float(input('Initial_velocity [m/s]:      ')))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong Value!')

    resume = Pr.call_block()

    print(f'Projectile launch point [m]: {resume[0]}...)
```